# Performing Efficient Select on Data with Different Time Resolution

Tags: filtering, dataset

I have two data sources with different time resolution. For data source A (temperature) I have about 1 s time resolution. For data source B (spectra) I have 0.01 s time resolution. I would like to average my spectra such that they have the same time resolution as the temperature data. Unfortunately, the spectral data is unevenly spaced, so it's not as simple as just figuring out the number of bins and applying a moving average filter. I'm extracting certain figures of merit from the spectra, so I don't need to average the WHOLE set of spectra over everything.

I think the solution to this is a `Select` query, but I'm not sure how to get the output that I want. I have the following:

```
temperatureTimes = someToyData;
spectraDataset = moreToyData;
synchroPoint = Nearest[temperatureTimes,spectraDataset[1,"time"]][[1]][[1]];
selectedTimes = Select[
  spectraDataset[;;,"time"]//Normal,
  temperatureTimes[[synchroPoint]]-Quantity[0.5,"Seconds"]
  <#<
  temperatureTimes[[synchroPoint]]+Quantity[0.5,"Seconds"]&];
```

This gives the time indices that are between plus or minus 0.5 seconds of the time point for the temperature data. Let's say that I have another column in `peakDataset` named `peak-position` that I would like to take the `Mean` over for these time points. Ideally I would like to be able to `Select` for the time points that meet the above condition, but return the `peak-position` data so that I can take the `Mean` over. I feel like there's probably an elegant way to do this using `Select` but I just can't find it.

Comment: Please provide `someToyData` and `moreToyData` so that people can run your code.